# How to use MySQL to remove random strings between two fixed strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, preg-replace

Here are some phrases in my MySQL database:

```
I love swimming and writing.
I love shopping and writing.
I love playing games and writing.
```

How can I change them to

```
I love writing.
I love writing.
I love writing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as removing a string in the middle, just as setting a constant string to anything that matches a pattern:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_column = 'I love writing.'
WHERE  my_column LIKE 'I love% writing.'
```